# Find the value of random variable

Tags: probability

I have 3 random numbers and their probability ratios are the following:

$$ P(C) = \frac{2}{3}P(A) = \frac{1}{4}P(B) $$

I have to find the values of each probability separately. So, what I do is the following:

$$ P(A) + P(B) + P(C) = 1 $$

From there, I do the following:

$$ P(A) + \frac{1}{4}\times \frac{2}{3}P(A) + \frac{2}{3}P(A) = 1 $$

I get different solution from the book. I suspect that my mistake is in the second value $$\frac{1}{4}\times \frac{2}{3}P(A)$$The correct answers in the book are: $ P(A) = \frac{3}{13}$, $P(B) = \frac{8}{13}$ and $P(C) = \frac{2}{13}$.

Comment: p(B)=(8/3)*p(A)

Comment: @Med using that I got the answers. However, may I ask how do I get that? Thanks.

Comment: Well, (2/3)p(A) = (1/4)p(B) hence p(B)=...p(A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple calculation but since you got stuck here it is $$\frac23P(A)=\frac14P(B)\implies\color{blue}{\frac41}\times\frac23P(A)=P(B)$$ but instead you have $$\color{red}{\frac14}\times\frac23P(A)=P(B)$$